# Getting error when using $messageCollection->getLastAddedMessage()->getText(); in magento 2

Tags: magento2.2, addtocart, success-message

I created a module to add available qty to cart when customer request more than available qty.
below is my code set.

> app/code/E25media/MagentoCommunity/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote">
    <plugin name="sr_check_stock" type="E25media\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\Quote" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
</config>
```

> app/code/E25media/MagentoCommunity/Plugin/Quote.php

```
<?php
namespace E25media\MagentoCommunity\Plugin;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject\Factory as DataObjectFactory;
class Quote
{
/**
 * @var StockRegistryInterface
 */
private $stockRegistry;

/**
 * @var ManagerInterface
 */
private $messageManager;

/**
 * @var DataObjectFactory
 */
private $objectFactory;

/**
 * Quote constructor.
 *
 * @param StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
 * @param ManagerInterface $messageManager
 * @param DataObjectFactory $objectFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry,
    ManagerInterface $messageManager,
    DataObjectFactory $objectFactory
) {
    $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
    $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
    $this->objectFactory = $objectFactory;
}

public function beforeAddProduct(
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $subject,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
    $request
) {
    if ($request === null) {
        $request = 1;
    }
    if (is_numeric($request)) {
        $request = $this->objectFactory->create(['qty' => $request]);
    }

    $messageCollection = $this->messageManager->getMessages(true);
    $messageCollection->getLastAddedMessage()->getText();   //Getting an error in this line.          
    if ($product->getId() && $request) {
        $stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItem($product->getId(), $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
        if ($stockItem->getQty() < $request->getQty()) {
            $remainingQty = $request->getQty() - $stockItem->getQty();
            $request->setQty($stockItem->getQty());
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('%1 item not available', $remainingQty));
        }
    }

    return [$product, $request];
}
}
```

as per requirement product is adding to the cart.
I want to concatenate the message and add some more part to the message to show in the product profile page.

```
$messageCollection->getLastAddedMessage()->getText();
```

above line my code is breaking. Any help to complete my task higly apreciated

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: no error messages, code break in that line.if i assign that line to a variable like this $message = $messageCollection->getLastAddedMessage()->getText(); , i am getting an error undefined variable $message.

Comment: can you try answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `true` parameter from `$this->messageManager->getMessages(true);`
Sending this parameter retrieves the messages from the session and clears them.
So the next time you call `messageManager->getMessages()` you get an empty list of messages.

Comment: thank you for your answer,I am still getting a break on the same line,if i remove the line code is running.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **`getMessages()`** method:

```
$messageCollection->getMessages()->getLastAddedMessage()->getText();
```

Comment: i am adding that getMessages() on upline like this $messageCollection = $this->messageManager->getMessages(true);

Comment: check marius answer. I think he is right